# Windows PowerShell show me this error : The string is missing the terminator: '

Tags: powershell

Salam, I formatted my computer a few days ago,
And i get this error, which I have not seen before.
I search on net but I don't find any useful solution.
Hope that you can help me guys !

error :

The string is missing the terminator: '.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

I think that the second error come from the first one

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

PowerShell version =>  5.1.19041.1320

Comment: The path after /configure has to be wrapped in quotes

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: how many versions of powershell are you running this code on? [*grin*] **_please remove the tags for any than you are not using when running the posted code._**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### PowerShell example Command:

```
unzipRelease –Src '$ReleaseFile' -Dst '$Destination'
```

Here the File Path is set in variable or writing directly in the command should include the quotes like above.

#### If you have any path which includes backslashes like:

`"C:\users\delsg\"`

When writing above path in PowerShell commands, rewrite it like:
`"C:\\users\\delsg\\"`

#### Few other examples were:

It works with single quotes. Command (or PowerShell) will take off the double quotes unless they're **back slashed**. Or put it in a script. Or pass the **argument** list as an array.

```
powershell Start-Process -Verb runas cmd '/k dir c:\'  
  
powershell Start-Process -Verb runas cmd \"/k dir c:\\\"  
  
powershell Start-Process -Verb runas cmd /k,dir,c:\
```